# How can I retrieve a list of all sent emails that have had clicks recorded in Mandrill?

Tags: mandrill

Having sent out 8k+emails via Mandrill I how need to be able to get a list of those emails which had been opened and then had a click recorded.
I can see the 1,000 most recent through the outbound report in Mandrill but can't seem to figure out how to generate a list of all outbound emails which have clicks recorded against them.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I know of two solutions here:

1) Use Mandrill's webhooks to receive and track open/click events on your own servers. [Documentation here.](https://help.mandrill.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583307-Message-Event-Webhook-format)

2) Use a secondary service to collect and parse mandrill analytics. I've used [sendwithus](http://sendwithus.com) before, but [keen.io](http://keen.io) may also work.

Comment: Thanks for that :)  Do you know if any of these solutions will allow me to find what I'm looking for retrospectively?

Comment: Ah, I don't. You could try connecting to the Mandrill API and pulling logs, but I suspect you'll run into the same problem you hit with the UI.